# Lambdas timing out

Tags: aws-lambda, timeout

I have a specific Lambda function invoked by SNS events that repeatedly times out in about 1/2 of its instances that seem to be running any of the handler code.

[image]

What's peculiar is that I have a number of log statements at the very start of the function handler that should be getting triggered.

I've tried increasing the timeout to 120 seconds, but this doesn't fix anything. I've also looked at the Lambda init logic (the code outside the main handler method) but its just simple imports and class initialisation, no database connections or HTTP requests that might be causing a timeout.

The handler logic does include database connections and network requests, but those were timing out then I'd expect to also see some logs prior to the timeouts.

When I view the Lambda logs by stream then around half of them look like the above and just time out, whereas the other half run as expected. Are streams specific to individual Lambda containers? If so then it looks as if there is a number of "dead" containers.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this in the past or has any idea what is going on?

Comment: If your lambda is in a vpc, check the subnet has NAT gateway, so the lambda can access to the internet.

Comment: @Lamanus that's a brilliant solution, I completely forgot that the lambda was in two subnets. After removing one of them it looks like the timeouts have stopped.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed after realising that the lambda was inside two different subnets, one of which didn't have a NAT gateway. After moving the lambda to a single subnet with a NAT the timeouts have stopped.